# Download file on Submission on contact form 7 form. The file is dynamically uploaded to the custom post type using acf

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, contact-form-7, acfpro

I have a custom post type 'plan'. There is acf field 'download_file' where a file is to be uploaded by admin.
For each post, the file is downloaded on submission of contact form. The file is fetched from the acf field.
How do i execute this?

cf7 shortcode -[contact-form-7 id="f35aa8c" title="Plan Download"]
post type -plan
acf field -flexible_content
layout - download_banner , field - download_file

cf7 shortcode -[contact-form-7 id="f35aa8c" title="Plan Download"]
post type -plan
acf field -flexible_content
layout - download_banner , field - download_file